# problem in boost-interprocess library

Tags: c++, boost, boost-interprocess

```
std::pair<int*, std::size_t> p = managed_shm.find<int>("Integer");
```

can someone provide me with the definition of this find method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow the code in the boost headers you'll find it, here is the starting point:

`class basic_managed_shared_memory` in `boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp` (version 1.4.5 is what I checked, you've not specified your version!)